# Effective Method for specifying user data

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm trying to create a program that can handle multiple users, each of which should have access to independent and private data. What is the best way to make it such that specific users can only see data that they've created or saved?

For instance, if I wanted to have an array of

```
myData = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: @"A", @"B", @"C", @"D", nil];
```

for each user, do I need to use core data to save the array, and somehow tag that array to that specific user?

Comment: what is the data that your setting per user?

Comment: the data is going to be a dictionary of names, and some related information (age, weight, etc). I just don't want all users to be able to access that same array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Without inconveniencing the user(s) you can't do it securely.**

**Any data stored on the device in your application's folders could be obtained by a user capable of accessing the phone.** (iTunes backups, etc). So storing data in folders based on username/user-id or storing things in a sqllite database (core data) partitioned by userid isn't going to help anything.

**You *could* attempt to encrypt the data** and keep user password hashes in the keychain - but you're really going to start jumping through hoops. Decrypting any serious amount of data will definitely make your app slower (if that matters to you).

The fact of the matter is, iOS just doesn't support multiple users at the moment - and that's what you really need - OS-level multi-user support.

Comment: So then I'm guessing that most apps which do have multiple users and persistent data are just storing the data on a remote server then? The data I'm trying to save for each user isn't going to be much more than a dictionary of names and pertinent information for each.

Comment: There aren't a ton of apps for iPhone/iPad that store **sensitive** data on the device. Remote server is definitely a better option for sensitive data than the device itself. iPhones/iPads are, by nature, an individualized device. They should be (at least) password-protected (on the lock screen) if anyone has sensitive data on their device.

Comment: Not that I'm interested in breaking into CoreData, but if there was sensitive data saved via some app, you're saying its really easy to access said data? What would that entail? Plugging in the device and file browsing via iTunes?

Comment: @DrTchocky: Plug into computer. Pair with iTunes. Perform "Backup" through iTunes. Open backup. Open SQL Lite file with any number of (even free) SQL Lite tools.

Answer (score 0):

If your going to use core data, add a new entity, call it user, and have it have an id.  Then save that id in your app, after the user loggs in, or authenticates with the app.  Then whenever you make a request for data, add the userID to the call.

Every entity that is specific to a user should have a userID field, and every call for data should be filtered by userID.

Comment: if I have a user entity, can I store arrays/dictionaries in that folder and retrieve it once the user signs in/is authenticated (using UIAlert)

Comment: ok, if you already store one file per user, what is the issue?  That sounds like its working to me.

Comment: Data saved in a sqllite file using CoreData can easily be retrieved by anyone with access to the device.

Comment: well, if were talking about snooping/security, then encrypt the data before storing it, was that the question?  I thought the question was how to have the separate the data, so each user only sees his/her own data.  Mu suggestion would give the appearance of different data per use, but it does not encrypt the data, any hacker with access to the divice or its computer with the backup can get the data.

Comment: Well, it seems that storing data so each user can only see their own data is fairly trivial (using coredata/sql), but making it secure is another thing (seems a bit more difficult). The biggest thing I'm worried about at the moment is simply storing the data.

Comment: awesome.  Then all you have to do is ensure that each table has the user key added to it, and when data is selected or inserted, also use the correct user key.

Answer (score 0):

Storing the data remotely seems to be the best option for your scenario.  My company has an iPad application that supports multi-users and we have a simple "login" service that authenticates a user and downloads their data to the device.  I guess the question is how large is your dataset and would it create a bad user experience by having to download?